# Replace a string with a format string

Tags: string, vb.net, replace

I have the following input:

```
Dim str_format as string = "XXXXX00000"
Dim str as string = "INV"
Dim int as integer = "56"
```

How can I replace `XXXXX` with `INV` and replace `00000` with `56`?

For the example above the result should be  `INVXX00056`.

`X` can only replace with alphabet and 0 can only replace with integer, if `str` has more than five alphabet. The extra alphabets will be thrown away because `str_format` only has five `X`. The same algorithm is true for the integer.

Example 2

```
Dim str_format as string = "XXX00000"
Dim str as string = "ABCD"
Dim int as integer = 654321
```

Expected result: `ABC54321`

Process:

```
1. ABCD XXX00000 654321
2. ABC DXX000006 54321
3. AB CDX00065 4321
4. A BCD00654 321
5. ABC06543 21
6. ABC65432 1
7. ABC54321
```

Comment: Looks like homework to me. Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: What you've done so far?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that just uses basic string methods and `PadLeft`/`PadRight` and a specific method to count occurrences of specific chars in the string. It assumes the format string can only contain `X` and `0` in the known order.

```
Public Function CountCharacter(ByVal value As String, ByVal ch As Char) As Integer
    Return value.Count(Function(c As Char) c = ch)
End Function

Public Sub run1()
    Dim str_format As String = "XXXXX00000" '"XXX00000"
    Dim str As String = "INV"
    Dim int As Integer = 56 '  ABC54321
    Dim xCnt As Integer = CountCharacter(str_format, "X")
    Dim zCnt As Integer = CountCharacter(str_format, "0")
    Dim result As String
    If xCnt > str.Length Then
        result = str.PadRight(xCnt, "X")
    Else
        result = str.Substring(0, xCnt)
    End If
    If zCnt > int.ToString().Length Then
        result = result & int.ToString().PadLeft(zCnt, "0")
    Else
        result = result & int.ToString().Substring(int.ToString().Length-zCnt
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(result)    
End Sub
```

Output for your both scenarios is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As Spidey mentioned... show some code. That said the process you describe is a bit long-winded.

The Letter part of the solution can be done by grabbing the first 3 characters of str using `Left(str,3)` this will bring in the leftmost 3 character (if there are less it will get what is there). Then check that you have 3 characters using `str.Length()`. If the length is less than 3 then append the appropriate number of 'X'.

The Numeric part can be done in a similar way. Your int is actually a string in your code above. If it was a real integer you can cast it to string. Use `Right(int,5)`. Again check to see you have 5 digits and if not prepend with appropriate number of 0.

Have a go... if you run into problems post your code and someone is bound to help.

**UPDATE**

As there have been actual answers posted here is my solution

```
Function FormatMyString(str As String, num as String) As String

    Dim result As String

    result = Left(str,3).PadRight(3, "X"c).ToUpper() & Right(num,5).PadLeft(5, "0"c)

    Return result

End Function
```

**UPDATE 2**

based on Wiktors answer... made an amendment to my solution to cope with different formats

```
Function FormatMyString(str As String, num as String, alpha as Integer, digits as Integer) As String

    Dim result As String

    result = Left(str, alpha).PadRight(alpha, "X"c).ToUpper() & Right(num, digits).PadLeft(digits, "0"c)

    Return result

End Function

To use... 
FormatMyString("ABCDE", "56",3 5) will return ABC00056
FormatMyString("ABCDE", "123456",4 3) will return ABCD456
FormatMyString("AB", "123456",4 3) will return ABXX456
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample

```
Dim str_format As String = str_format.Replace("XXX", "ABC")
Msgbox(str_format )
```

As we assume that the `X` is 3 only. I dont want to give you more it is a start and everything will be easy.

If that kind of format is fix I mean the number of `X` will go or down then you can make a conditional statement based on the length of string